# How to achieve the following distribution in python random module or numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, random

1. There would be 10000 samples.
2. The mode of this distribution would be 100
3. The distribution will mostly have values between 0  to 200, but
   few values ( with decreasing probablity can be as high as 5000  )

The probability distribution curve for the values would somewhat look
like:

[image]

I have tried using `random.triangular` and `numpy.random.triangular` to generate such distributions with given low,high and mode, but triangular
distribution is not very relevant to these requirements.
How can such a normal distribution be achieved with random/numpy modules,
using low (0) ,high (5000) ,mode (100) values provided ?

Comment: There are infinitely many ways to create a distribution that is roughly that shape.  Do you have more information about the process that generates the samples?  That might help guide the choice of an appropriate model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a Lévy distribution, or something similar:
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lévy_distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_distribution)

You could maybe use this and the scale it:
http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.stats.levy.html

Update:
Ok, so a Fréchet distribution looks rather to be yours:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.frechet_r.html

Comment: seems like the Fréchet distribution was removed in the [1.6.0 release](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.1.6.0.html#scipy-stats-changes)